# jquery - syntax for dynamically change css transition time

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I'm trying to dynamically change the css transition time but without success...
I've searched for it, but I don't understand how to use the syntax:

```
var myDiv = $('.myDiv');
var papa = 2;
var pepe = $('.myDiv').left();
var popo = ((pepe - 10) * 0.35);


function pause(){
  myDiv.css({
      left: myDiv.css('left')
  });
}

function goRight(){
  myDiv.css({
      transition: "left " + papa + "s linear",
      left: 250
  });
}

function goLeft(){
  myDiv.css({
      transition: "left " + popo + "s linear",
      left: 0
  });
}
```

Comment: Try to replace myDiv and pepe with actual $('.myDiv') and $('.myDiv').left(). I suppose it's not a good idea to do "var myDiv = $('.myDiv');" before page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
transition: <property> || <duration> || <timing-function> || <delay> [, ...];
```

Note that the duration must come before the delay if the latter is specified. Individual transitions combined in shorthand declarations:

```
-webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
-moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
-ms-transition: left 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s; /* IE10 is actually unprefixed */
-o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
transition: left 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
```

then  :

```
myDiv.css({

      // Repeat value for each transition to be compatible to all browsers

  });
```